# Terminal displaying two hostnames

Tags: linux, centos7

I am seeing 2 hostnames like this when I login to my centos machine

```
[MoonX-Ex-WEB-HOST]: [centos@moonx-webhost-uat ~]$
```

I recently changed the hostname using this command

```
hostnamectl set-hostname <newHostName>
```

When I see check for hostname its showing "new one". But on screen I am getting this two hostnames [old and new].

If anyone know this issue please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That a previous hostname is shown seems strange.

You should examine your prompt configuration by doing `echo $PS1`.
On my CentOS 7 default is `[\u@\h \W]\$` where for example `\u` means *display the logged in user*

To alter the prompt (for the current user) you could add following to your `~/.bashrc`

```
PS1='[\u@\h \W]\$ '
```

and source/relog to see the change

Comment: Even my $PS1 value shows same 
echo $PS1
[MoonX-Ex-WEB-HOST]: [\u@\h \W]$